# Foreach running out of index with a keyvaluepair ienumerable?

Tags: c#

I've run into a strange Problem which I can't imagine as to WHY. Whenever I use a foreach to run over a custom filled IENumerable of KeyValuePair entries I get an error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Prameter name: index`

The question is: WHY does this happen?

Code:

```
private void extractData(List<string> data)
{
  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> extData;
  extData =
    data.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0)
    .Select((s, i) => 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, data.ElementAt(i * 2 + 1)));

  string extJournal = String.Empty;
  List<KeyValuePair> myData = new List<KeyValuePair>();

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in extData)
  {
      //1
     myData.Add(keyValuePair);
      //2
     extJournal+= string.Format("Metadata({0}): {1}{2}", 
          keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value, System.Environment.NewLine);
     //3
  }

}
```

As additional info here: *The error happens seemingly NOT durign the data sets but during the foreach part (if I put a debug message instead of //1 - 3 I get all 3 Outputs but still run into an error which Points towards an error directly in the foreach execution itself).*

Comment: is this all the code in foreach?

Comment: Did you copy this over properly? Where does `splittedData` come from? These are syntax errors (the `List<KeyValuePair> myData` line)

Comment: @sertsedat yepp I can't fathom the why as I tried everything I could think of there. I even took one full hour to make sure that it is really Happening inside /with the foreach Loop and was quite....shocked.

Comment: The LINQ query gets executed in the `foreach` but the error is in the query. Use `ElementAtOrDefault` instead of `ElementAt` which returns `null` then and/or check your logic.

Comment: @ikkentim tnx was a copy & paste error (I excluded about a dozen of lines where I transformed the real data into the  string Array data (originally called splitted data then)

Comment: `data.ElementAt(i * 2 + 1)` won't fly. And because an `IEneumerable` is lazy evaluated  you see the error pop up later in the foreach.

Comment: @Thomas - copy/paste from actual code can't produce errors like this. Do take the time to create a [mcve] and only post it after verification.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  it was the lazy Evaluation that produced the error if you mean that (see the answer).

Comment: @TimSchmelter tried it.  And yepp  got null values. tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your `Where` selector

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> extData;
  extData =
    data.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0)
    .Select((s, i) => 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, data.ElementAt(i * 2 + 1)));
```

If the list has 3 elements, for the 3rd element `i(2) % 2` will be 0. In the `Select` element (i(1) * 2 + 1) == 3 , the 4th element is selected, but this is outside of the range of the list.

Change the `Where` selector to include `&& i <= data.Count - 2`

Please note Linq queries are run lazily, for **every** iteration, not at the moment you define the query.

Comment: so the reason why the error appears in the  foreach is that the whole Thing is not "run through" when the extdata is set but later on in the foreach?

Comment: tnx worked quite well now. (alternative is to replace elementat with ElementAtOrDefault  and then checking for null keys.